# xxx.hbm.xml not found but it actually exists

Tags: java, hibernate, hbmxml

I get this error when I run Tomcat:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>    org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource:
>    com/itheima/elec/domain/ElecText.hbm.xml not found

But it is really exists in my project:

[image]

And in my Hibernate configuration is like below:

```
<session-factory>
    ...
    <mapping resource="com/itheima/elec/domain/ElecText.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/itheima/elec/domain/ElecCommonMsg.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

I don't know where the issue is, can some friend help me?

Comment: You should use <mapping class=..> instead of <mapping resource=..>

Comment: If your using maven then the hbm.xml files should be in src/main/resouces/com/itheima/...

Comment: You are looking at the wrong place : your screen-shot show a source folder, while the error is a runtime one (be it in junit test, or  the deployement of the webapp on a prod server). With a resource not found at runtime, you need to inspect the runtime classpath, and search on this classpath the missing resource. If you need help on this, you'll need to include more information on the runtime producing this error. With tomcat, look at what is inside the war in the folder : /WEB-INF/classes/com/... you should find the hbm.xml there (if in same module than the webapp)

Answer (score 0):

Please use @Annotations for the classes inside your domain folder,then you no need to use hbm.xml files. After that in hibernate.cfg.xml file use 
''

Comment: <mapping resource="com/itheima/elec/domain/ElecText"/>